# Handle reading timing in Python using pySerial

Tags: python

I'm not sure about how to properly handle timing readings from serial inside a Python script. I need to read a value every **5 seconds**.

From Arduino I could do,

```
Serial.println(value);
delay(5000); // should I wait here?
```

Inside Python script I could do,

```
import serial
import time

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM1', 9600, timeout=5) # should I set timeout?

while True and arduino.isOpen():

    try:    
        value = arduino.readline().strip()
        print value

        time.sleep(5) # should I wait here?

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nClosing..."
        arduino.close()
```

EDIT: Apart from that, the first reading is always wrong, like if there was something in the reading buffer.
I've found out that to solve that I should add `arduino.flushInput()` just after opening the port.

Comment: Do you need to "read a value every 5 seconds" or "transmit a value from the Arduino to the host every 5 seconds"?

Comment: Arduino is writing values to the serial, and I'm reading the serial inside my python script.

Comment: Yes, we all get that. What we need to know is which one needs to be in control of the timing.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for replying. I'm not sure which, what is the proper way to do this simple stuff? I mean, my sketch just sends temperature values, it's the only thing it does. My python script would read those values and print them every 5 seconds.

Comment: Does it just *keep* sending them as quickly as possible, and the Python program is supposed to only display the ones that show up every 5 seconds?

Comment: Well, that should be an option. Another I think would be that Arduino sends every 5 seconds and Python is always listening, waiting for that value. Which one should be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that it depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish. If there is nothing else to be done on the Arduino then it is fine to have it sit and wait; on the other hand if there is nothing else for the python script to do then it is fine for it to sit and wait, but there is no reason for both of them wait.

### Arduino `delay`s

You don't need to deal with the timing delay in python if the Arduino is `delay`ing. According to [the documentation](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#readline) `readline` will wait until it has received a value or until the timeout is reached. That said, I would make the timeout slightly longer than the delay on the Arduino side of things.

Note that `readline` will block your program from doing anything else while it waits. As such, It is pretty useful to explore python [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) when you are writing a program which collects data over a serial stream unless the program is *only* collecting data.

### Python `sleep`s

If there is other stuff to be done on the Arduino (perhaps if you are doing some filtering of the temperature data using the Arduino so as to reduce noise) then it might make more sense for it to push data to the serial stream at the end of each `loop`, and for the python script to only read the data every 5 seconds. In this case you could have python `sleep` and use no delay (or a shorter delay) on the Arduino. You can achieve this behavior without resorting to using `sleep` by using a [`timer` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) to periodically call a function that `open`s the serial stream (possibly flush it), reads the data, processes it, and closes the serial stream.

Comment: Thanks! There was another factor in my Python script, and that was the `while True` statement. In this simple example, it doesn't matter what timeout value is because `readline` would be called again on the next loop. However, I guess I should notice that `readline` is blocking everything else in my script, if there was another thing to do.

Comment: I was considering the (remote) possibility of your Arduino and computer being perfectly synchronized, such that the `readline` times out after reading half of the line, and then immediately reads the second half of the line on the next iteration of the loop. This is an admittedly far-fetched possibility, but by making your timeout longer than 5 seconds you limit the likelihood of it.